# How can I get nm to show the return types of a function?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to write a script to produce a 'fake' version of a huge and messy code library, I thought using 'nm' on the binary and filtering just the text symbols might be the way to go, but I can't seem to get nm to display the return type of the function as well as the signature.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Toolchain and binary format?  If you're trying to extract return type from just symbol name on anything following Intel's Itanium ABI for C++ (which includes GCC on most targets), this is largely impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of the function is not part of the name mangling.  Return types are enforced by the compiler directly based on type rules.

It is possible to call a function defined as, for example, returning `int`, and having a declaration for it returning, say `char`.  Most tools will not notice the mismatch.  Considering all they ways you might shoot yourself in the foot, this isn't too bad since you would have to have gone out of your way to do it.  Like by not using a header file common to both modules.

Comment: I suspected it was as such, but what you're saying means it doesn't matter if I have the header files, which I do :-)